# "Aren't your hair long enough to be washed often?"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage

Is this statement grammatically correct?

> Aren't your hair long enough to be washed often?

Should I say "Isn't your Hair...?"

Comment: Where did you come across it?

Comment: Idiomatically "I need to wash my hair: my hair is really dirty."